# Navigation not working in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, jetpack-compose-navigation

Trying to use NavGraph and BottomNavigation. The home screen is displayed correctly. When I try to click a button and navigate, an error occurs

java.lang.NullPointerException
at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1652)

Two screens with inscriptions. No complex features.
I can't understand the reason at all.

```
@Composable
fun App() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    //
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = { AppBottomNavigation() }
    ) { padding ->
        AppNavHost(
            Modifier.padding(padding),
            navController,
            "home1")
    }
}
@Composable
fun AppNavHost(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController(),
    startDestination: String = "home2"
) {
    NavHost(
        modifier = modifier,
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = startDestination
    ) {
        composable(route = "home1") {
            ListHotelScreen()
        }
        composable(route = "home2") {
            ListBookingScreen()
        }
    }
}
@Composable
fun AppBottomNavigation(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    //
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    //
    BottomNavigation(modifier) {
        BottomNavigationItem(
            icon = {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.Home,
                    contentDescription = null
                )
            },
            label = {
                Text(stringResource(R.string.home1))
            },
            selected = true,
            onClick = { navController.navigate("home1") }
        )
        BottomNavigationItem(
            icon = {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.AccountCircle,
                    contentDescription = null
                )
            },
            label = {
                Text(stringResource(R.string.home2))
            },
            selected = false,
            onClick = { navController.navigate("home2") }
        )
    }
}
@Composable
fun ListHotelScreen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(
        modifier
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            .padding(vertical = 16.dp)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "ListHotelScreen",
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
        )
    }
}
@Composable
fun ListBookingScreen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(
        modifier
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            .padding(vertical = 16.dp)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "ListBookingScreen",
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h3,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one navController everywhere

```
@Composable
fun App() {
    val navController = rememberNavController() 
    //
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = { AppBottomNavigation(navController) } //Here
    ) { padding ->
        AppNavHost(
            Modifier.padding(padding),
            navController,
            "home1")
    }
}
```

Remove new navController definition, use existing one

```
@Composable
fun AppBottomNavigation(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, 
                        navController: NavHostController) {
    //
    //val navController = rememberNavController() - remove
    //
    BottomNavigation(modifier) {
        BottomNavigationItem(
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to enter the nav controller as parameter to the AppBottomNavigation